# Page lifecycle events not firing for user control on page layout when anonymous user

Tags: page-layout, anonymous-authentication, user-controls

I'm using SharePoint 2010.

I have a custom user control on a publishing page layout. When an authenticated user visits a page that uses the page layout everything works fine. When an anonymous user visits a page that uses the page layout, the content that should come from the user control is not shown. After some debugging I determined that the page life-cycle events (i.e. Render and CreateChildControls) are not firing on the user control when an anonymous user visits the page.

Anyone experienced this before?

Comment: are you sure that your control is not wrapped by a SPSecurityTrimmedControl or sg like that ? Forget that the default control does not allow anoymous permissions to be set on

Comment: "Forget that the default control does not allow anoymous permissions to be set on" - can you please rephrased this, I don't understand.

Comment: I think I remember there being a problem like this in the SP2010 Beta, but I thought for sure it was fixed in the RC or RTM.  Just curious...if you put a Page_Load event in the user control code-behind, does it fire?

Comment: When you use the SPSecurityTrimmedControl, you must set a level of permissions. Anonymous level is not one of them. And my guess is that you didn't extend it to allow anonymous permission level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the culprit was an EditModePanel. As soon as I took the control out of the panel it worked fine. I checked and the same applies to standard server controls (e.g. TextBox), they do not render for anonymous users when inside an EditModePanel.